# mysql bulk import files to longtext

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem for which I already have programmed a solution, but it is extremely slow. So I need an huge improvement on it or maybe a hint for another way.

the situation is as follows:

There is a directory on local disk containing many subfolders and in total about 100000 files that take about 25 GB, so one file has about 250 KB. All files are text files and I don't know the structure of the pathtree of the main directory. The pathtree, the filenames and their content can change regulary.

What I want to achieve is, to import all these files to a mysql-table which should hold at least the path to the file and it's content.

for example:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   NAME      +   TYP             +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   path      +   varchar(500)    +
+   content   +   longtext        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

My first approach is a java-programm that searches for all files in the main-directory recursively. Each file is read and the content is stored in a String. After that I call INSERT for every file.

I started the programm but in the first hour it has only processed 3600 files, so just 3,6 %. 27 hours for the total import is a little bit to much. ;-)

Does anyone have an idea how I can improve that?

I don't think that I can use LOAD DATA INFILE in any way in this case. Maybe there's another mysql-function that could help?

A java-solution is preferred, but C/C++ is also possible. Maybe someone can guess how much this could speed up the process?

Changes in the settings of the mysql-server are also possible. But I'm not into that topic.

System is a mysql-server on linux, files are also stored on the same server. The solution should be os-independent in general.

Many thanks for all advices!

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was really easy.

First of all, the main improvement I got with the use of the "load_file"-function of mysql that I used directly in the insert statement.

Further I don't search for all files now in the java programm. Instead I first created a txt-file containing all file-paths using the find-command from linux and then loop over the lines.